# Cordova Visual Studio 2015 RC Community : Remote Device iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm currently discovering Visual Studio 2015 RC Community to develop mobile applications with Cordova.

I have a Mac (OS X Yosemite) with the necessary tools to use the iOS Remote Agent from within Visual Studio. I have an iPad connected to my Mac to deploy a basic Cordova application on this device.

Unfortunately I don't understand why in the list of iOS devices, I have no "remote device" (as shown in the screenshot tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dn757056.aspx ) to deploy the application on the iPad connected to my Mac.

How can I resolve this problem?

Thank you for your answsers ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a localized VS version as this is a known issue in localized version? If so, then as a workaround, can you try copying %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\iOSRemotEDevice.xml into the fr-FR folder. The string wont be localized though.

Comment: Like you said, this file was not in the fr-FR folder. But i did not find it in " %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\iOSRemotEDevice.xml ", I found it in en-US.   So I put it in fr-FR and it seems to work ! Thank you !

Comment: This is unbelievable! Same problem for german and the answer is really hard to find in google and especially pretty ridiculous!
Searched for "visual studio 2015 cordova ios remote build remote unavailable / not available / not visible" and so on...